# Proving a limit property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to prove the following property:

Let $(a_n),(b_n)$ be Sequences in $\mathbb{R}$, $a_n\to a $ and $b_n\to b$

$(\exists\ n_0 \in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n \geq n_0: a_n \leq b_n)\Rightarrow a\leq b $,
suppose $a>b\ , \epsilon:=(a-b)/2 $

At some point my script mentions that $-(a_n-a)<\epsilon $ and $b_n - b<\epsilon$

Could someone explain to me the intution behind the step above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe tell us what $a,b$ are ?

Comment: Who is “We”${}{}$?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to prove that, provided the first sequence converges to $a$ and the second one to $b$, it holds $a\le b$.

Suppose not, so $a>b$. Therefore $\varepsilon=(a-b)/2>0$ and we can find $n_1\ge n_0$ such that, for $n\ge n_1$,
$$
|a_n-a|<\varepsilon,\qquad |b_n-b|<\varepsilon \tag{*}
$$
This translates to
$$
-\varepsilon<a_n-a<\varepsilon,\qquad -\varepsilon<b_n-b<\varepsilon
$$
The first pair of inequalities implies $-(a_n-a)<\varepsilon$. You also can isolate $b_n-b<\varepsilon$ and derive a contradiction.

On the other hand, I'd more simply rewrite (*) as
$$
a-\varepsilon<a_n<a+\varepsilon,\qquad b-\varepsilon<b_n<b+\varepsilon
$$
and observe that $b+\varepsilon=(a+b)/2=a-\varepsilon$, so this becomes
$$
\frac{3b-a}{2}<b_n<\frac{a+b}{2}<a_n<\frac{3a-b}{2}
$$
and the central inequalities provide the contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, can I rewrite every limit definition $|a_n-a|<\epsilon $,  as   $ -\epsilon<a_n-a<\epsilon$  ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, of course: $|x|<y$ is exactly the same as $-y<x<y$ (meaning that the inequalities both hold).